# Auto vectorization Region of interest (crop)

Tags: c++, gcc, crop, vectorization, roi

I have a library which has some image processing algorithms including a Region of Interest (crop) algorithm. When compiling with GCC, the auto vectorizer speeds up a lot of the code but worsens the performance of the Crop algorithm. Is there a way of flagging a certain loop to be ignored by the vectorizer or is there a better way of structuring the code for better performance?

```
for (RowIndex=0;RowIndex<Destination.GetRows();++RowIndex)
{
    rowOffsetS = ((OriginY + RowIndex) * SizeX) + OriginX;
    rowOffsetD = (RowIndex * Destination.GetColumns());
    for (ColumnIndex=0;ColumnIndex<Destination.GetColumns();++ColumnIndex)
    {
        BufferSPtr=BufferS + rowOffsetS + ColumnIndex;
        BufferDPtr=BufferD + rowOffsetD + ColumnIndex;
        *BufferDPtr=*BufferSPtr;
    }
}
```

Where
`SizeX` is the width of the source
`OriginX` is the left of the region of interest
`OriginY` is the top of the region of interest

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand your question correctly. You want to either flag that loop to not be vectorized or restructure it for better performance? Seems like a contradiction to me. But in regards to performance: Can the two ranges overlap? If not: Are you using `__restrict` on the pointer to make that clear to the compiler? Pointeraliasing is a big showstopper for optimization. Besides: have you thought about using `std::copy` for your inner loop? That might be better optimized and makes your code shorter.

Comment: It does seem like a contradiction, but that's the idea. Vectorizing currently worsens performance, so either disabling it for this loop or  improving the code are two options I could think of! I'll give restrict and copy a go.

Comment: You might want to mention that the performance for crop worsens in that case in your question. As it stands I assumed that the performance of the Crop algorithm remaining unchanged by the vectorization. In case you don't know it yet, the `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=n` flag might help you getting more concrete informations about what the optimizer is doing and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything about changing the optimization flags for a loop, however according to the documentation you can use the attribute `optimize` (look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) and [here](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/cc.html)) on a function to override the optimization settings for that function somewhat like this:

```
void foo() __attribute__((optimize("O2", "inline-functions")))
```

If you want to change it for several functions, you can use `#pragma GCC optimize` to set it for all following functions ([look here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas)).

So you should be able to compile the function containing crop with a different set of optimization flags, omitting the auto-vectorization. That has the disadvantage of hardcoding the compilation flags for that function, but is the best I found.

With regards to restructuring for better performance the two points I already mentioned in the comments come to mind (assuming the ranges can't overlap):

- declaring the pointers as `__restrict` to tell the compiler that they don't alias (the area pointed to by one pointer won't be accessed by any other means inside the function). The possibility of pointer aliasing is a major stumbling block for the optimizer, since it can't easily reorder the accesses if it doesn't know if writing to `BufferD` will change the contents of `BufferS`.
- Replacing the inner loop with a call to copy:

  ```
  std::copy(BufferS + rowOffsetS, BufferS + rowOffsetS + Destination.GetColumns(), BufferD + rowOffsetD);
  ```

  The `copy` function is likely to be pretty well optimized (probably forwarding the arguments to `memmove`), so that might make your code faster, while also making your code shorter (always a plus).

Comment: Using copy disables the auto vectorization of this loop **and** provides slightly better performance over what I had earlier. Thanks!